# Sending data to Azure Event Hub using Synapse Spark

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

Working on Synapse Analytics Studio using PySpark and while I was able to read the Event Hub messages, I am not able to produce messages. Getting an error when using the save method.

```py
### %pip install azure-eventhub
import json
connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://::hidden::"
ehConf = { }
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)

# Create the positions
startingEventPosition = {
  "offset": -1,  
  "seqNo": -1,            #not in use
  "enqueuedTime": None,   #not in use
  "isInclusive": True
}
ehConf["eventhubs.startingPosition"] = json.dumps(startingEventPosition)
df = spark.read.format("eventhubs").options(**ehConf).load()
display(df)
```

Works... I can see the messages complete with sequenceNumber, body, et al

Now, I want to write to the event hub from a data frame.

```py
df1 = spark.read.parquet(silver_path) # confirmed to have data via display(df1)
df1 \
  .select(struct(*[c for c in df1.columns]).alias("body")) \
  .write \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .save()
```

Results in:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4089.save.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsWriter$.validateQuery(EventHubsWriter.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsWriter$.write(EventHubsWriter.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSourceProvider.createRelation(EventHubsSourceProvider.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:901)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:249)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried in my environment I got same error when writing dataframe to event hub.

[image]

To resolve this error, try the below code.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df1 \
  .select(F.to_json(F.struct("*")).alias("body")) \
  .write \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .save()
```

Here my `df1` dataframe contains a sample of 5 rows.

[image]

I have read the data from event hub, and you can see 5 new rows are ingested into event hub from dataframe `df1`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. ' F.to_json(F.struct("*") ' was the clincher!